# No triangles or rectangles in a Moore graph of diameter 2.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Can somebody explain why there cannot be any triangles or squares in a Moore graph with diameter 2? This was stated without proof in my class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which definition you're using, but [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph), a useful one is that a Moore graph is a graph $G$ of diameter $k$ and girth $2k + 1$.

That means if $k = 2$, then the smallest cycle in $G$ has $5$ vertices.  Having a triangle or a square would contradict that.

Comment: It says that this is an equivalent definition to the one with the sum (which I a was given). Can you provide a proof that the two are equivalent?

Comment: Actually no, I couldn't prove it myself nor find the original proof.  Apparently it's in the paper "There is no irregular Moore graph" by R. Singleton (1968), but I could not find the paper online.  I'll keep looking a bit.